# Running custom zsh function for tmux status bar not displaying output

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm wrote a function called `test_status` that I am trying to incorporate in my tmux status bar. To give some background, my tests will output to a file called `.guard_result` with either `success` or `failure` and the `test_status` function reads from that file and echoes a  if my tests are passing and a ❤️ if they are failing.

The good news is running `test_status` works just fine, I'm just having trouble getting it to work with tmux.  What am I missing here?

```
#  ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh

function test_status {
  if [ ! -f "./.guard_result" ]; then
    echo "?"
    return 1
  fi

  result="$(cat ./.guard_result)"

  if [[ $result == *"success"* ]]
  then
    echo "";
  elif [[ $result == *"fail"* ]]
  then
    echo "❤️";
  fi
}
```

This function works... Here is Tmux configuration (which doesn't show result):

```
# ~/.tmux.conf

set -g status-right "#(test_status) #[fg=colour245]%d %b %Y #[fg=white]:: #[fg=colour245]%l:%M %p"
```

I know I must be missing something simple... Thanks for your help!

Comment: `tmux` uses `sh` by default. I don't recall if there is an option to specify which shell to use for `#(...)` commands

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` passes shell commands to `/bin/sh` not `zsh`. And even if `tmux` would use `zsh`, the function would not be available in that context as `~/.zshrc`, which loads *oh-my-zsh*, is only read for interactive shells.

In order to get the the output of `test_status` into `tmux`, I would suggest to put the function into a zsh script and call that.

You can either source `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh` from within the script and then call `test_status`:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
#  ^ make sure this reflects the path to zsh (`type zsh`)

source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh
test_status
```

Or you can just put the entire function into the script, so as to not clutter `alias.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
function test_status {
    if [ ! -f "./.guard_result" ]; then
        echo "?"
        return 1
    fi

    result="$(cat ./.guard_result)"

    if [[ $result == *"success"* ]]
    then
        echo "";
    elif [[ $result == *"fail"* ]]
    then
        echo "❤️";
    fi
}
```

Safe the script somewhere (e.g. `/path/to/test_status.zsh`), make it executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/test_status.zsh`) and call it by path in the `tmux` configuration.